# String_Split on delimiter '.' SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split

I have an issue when parsing out a particular field of data, and I'm at a block on how to solve it, so I'm hoping I can gain some insight on how to solve it.

I have a field being brought [ItemCategory] that contains instances like...

1. Instance:  TennisShoes.Laces
2. Instance:  HikingBoot-Dr.Marten.Laces

(I cannot change the delimiter from '.' to '|' as I don't control the source)

the code being used to separate  the instances is as follows:

```
SELECT 
[Program] = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(c.[ItemCategory], CHARINDEX('.',c.[ItemCategory] + '.') - 1)))
,[Category] = LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(c.[ItemCategory],LEN(c.[ItemCategory]) - CHARINDEX('.',c.[ItemCategory]))))
```

So my issue when the DHikingBoot-Dr.Marten.Laces instance passes through the code it becomes.

```
[Program] = HikingBoot-Dr
[Category] = Marten.Laces
```

How would I make it to ignore the first '.' and delimit on the second '.', while still maintaining correctness for the first instance.

Thank you for your time.. any advice is helpful.

Comment: what version of sql server?   is that consistent in all the data?  You have a maximum number of 3 periods and it if it 3 then skip the first one?  or does it always end with `.Laces`?

Comment: It is always a good idea to identify the actual version of sql server you are using. TRIM now does the work of both LTRIM and RTRIM.

Answer (score 0):

Give this one a try for grabbing the end.

```
RIGHT(c.[ItemCategory], CHARINDEX(REVERSE('.'), REVERSE(c.[ItemCategory])) -1)
```

Comment: What is the benefit of `REVERSE('.')`?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest revisiting how you are storing this data, if you can, as it is flawed and will continue to give you challenges.

But that aside, this solution assumes "Category" will not include a period and the data will always end with *`.category`*

A few tweaks to what you had started, we'll use [REVERSE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/reverse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to basically determine the length of "Category" when using LEFT().  Then when we do "Program" we subtract that from the total length when using the RIGHT()

```
DECLARE @testdata TABLE
(
    [sampledata] NVARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO @testdata (
                          [sampledata]
                      )
VALUES ( N'TennisShoes.Laces' )
     , ( 'HikingBoot-Dr.Marten.Laces' );

SELECT LEFT([sampledata], LEN([sampledata]) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE([sampledata]))) AS [Program]
     ,RIGHT([sampledata], CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE([sampledata])) -1) AS [Category]
FROM   @testdata;
```

You can also use [SUBTRING()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) along with [REVERSE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/reverse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> For category, reverse the data, find the first period, parse the
> value and reverse it back.
>
> For Program, reverse the data, go 1 past the first period to the end
> and reverse it back.

```
DECLARE @testdata TABLE
    (
        [sampledata] NVARCHAR(100)
    );

INSERT INTO @testdata (
                          [sampledata]
                      )
VALUES ( N'TennisShoes.Laces' )
     , ( 'HikingBoot-Dr.Marten.Laces' );

SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([sampledata]), CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE([sampledata])) + 1, LEN([sampledata]))) AS [Program]
     , REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([sampledata]), 1, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE([sampledata])) - 1)) AS [Category]
FROM   @testdata;
```

Both giving you results of:

```
Program               Category
--------------------- ----------
TennisShoes           Laces
HikingBoot-Dr.Marten  Laces
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to select only last part after the `.`, then you can reverse the string, find `charindex` and do `left` and `right` with that position:

```
with s as (
  select 'TennisShoes.Laces' as inst union
  select 'HikingBoot-Dr.Marten.Laces' union
  select 'Test'
)
, pos as (
  select
    s.*,
    charindex('.', reverse(inst)) as pos
  from s
)
select
  ltrim(rtrim(left(inst, len(inst) - pos))) as program,
  ltrim(rtrim(right(inst, nullif(pos - 1, -1)))) as category
from pos

program              | category
:------------------- | :-------
HikingBoot-Dr.Marten | Laces   
TennisShoes          | Laces   
Test                 | null
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=8b9c7ec4f2f37c8d49e3f23ea8486ae3)

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.